# DNX (rc1) web command does not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I have troubles with running MVC6 application. 
Project builds well, no errors, packages are loaded correctly ( no errors due restoring)

[Here is my global.json code. As you see, both dnx versions in app and on machine are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USD7N.jpg)

Sure, I am using VS2015 with WebTools-beta8 and DotNetVersionManager-beta8.

This is part of my project.json:

```
"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
},

"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "Content"
],
"publishExclude": [
    "Content",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
}
```

When i click on 'Web' command, project builds, but then cmd window show me next message:[('Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstract')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji8Ba.jpg)

And Output/Debug window ends with
"The program '[14200] dnx.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1)."

I have updated dnvm and webTools, but problem is not solved. By the way, on another PC, project runs well, so problem might be with my dnx.

Comment: Aren't you by any chance running a project with rc1 packages using beta8  runtime?

Comment: Are you sure that you have all needed packges in 'dependencies' section? Show it please.

Comment: I have the same behavior when referencing projects on net451 framework.

Comment: Try to remove all downloaded nuget packages from `%UserProfile/.dnx/packages`, then do `dnu restore` again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried restoring your dependencies from a command prompt?

To do so just run 'dnu restore' from a command prompt. Make sure the command prompts working directory is at your MVC project.

Comment: Hi, I copied my project to another location in C: .. then i used powershell to run dnu restore. try to launch the app again, but i still get the same error

Comment: Hi Luis, sorry for late reply. What is your error? And can you show us your dnvm list results, dnx --version result, your global.json & project.json (just showing the parts for the dependencies and frameworks)?