# IIS not running ASP.net 5 RC2 MVC 6 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

IIS from Visual Studio will not launch my application.  It seems as if Visual Studio is trying to build my project with the incorrect DNX version.  However, under my application profile it has the correct solution DNX version of 1.0.0-rc2-16357.  When I attempt to launch the application through IIS Express, the app throws up a blank web page and it immediately stops executing with 'dnx.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).'  There are no exceptions when this happens.  However, I am able to launch it through the command line using

```
dnvm upgrade -u
dnu restore 
dnx ef migrations add initial
dnx ef database update
dnx web
```

My project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-*",

        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.HttpOverrides": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",

        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-*"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "MyWebApplication",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

Application failing under Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.02.247

Comment: Possible duplicate: [DNX (rc1) web command does not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652357/dnx-rc1-web-command-does-not-working).  Please specify your MSVS version. Please consider installing  [Glimpse](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse): it should help troubleshoot the problem.  This article might also help:[Debugging ASP.Net 5 Framework Code with MSVS 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx).  Please post back what you find!

Comment: Unfortunately there does not appear to be a version of Glimpse compatible with MVC 6.  Also, new projects do not appear to be using a global.json file at least in VS2015.